# Having more than One-To-Many relations to a single class

Tags: android, ormlite

Guess that I have a class named `Many`. There are two other classes `One1` and `One2` that have a collection of `Many`:

Class One1:

```
public class One1 {
    // ...
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    private ForeignCollection<Many> events;
}
```

Class One2:

```
public class One2 {
    // ...
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    private ForeignCollection<Many> events;
}
```

`Many` entity has only one relation at a time. My question is: How should I manage such relation on the `Many` side?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: "Many entity has only one relation at a time". Does it mean that `Many` could have relation or with `One1`, or with `One2`? And never to both in same time?

Comment: Yes. P_ID in many side holds the ID of ONE1 or ONE2

Answer (score 0):

My idea is next. `Many` class has 2 `foreign` fields and controls their filling by setters. `One1` and `One2` use `foreignFieldName` attribute to refer to different fields at `Many`. See implementation bellow:

**Many**

```
public class Many {

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private One1 mOne1;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private One2 mOne2;

    public void setOne1(One1 one1) {
        mOne1 = one1;
        mOne2 = null;
    }

    public void setOne2(One2 one2) {
        mOne2 = one2;
        mOne1 = null;
    }
}
```

**One1**

```
public class One1 {
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, foreignFieldName = "mOne1")
    private ForeignCollection<Many> mEvents;

    public ForeignCollection<Many> getEvents() {
        return mEvents;
    }
}
```

**One2**

```
public class One2 {

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, foreignFieldName = "mOne2")
    private ForeignCollection<Many> mEvents;


    public ForeignCollection<Many> getEvents() {
        return mEvents;
    }


}
```